# GetLastError custom attribute

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I would like to include `GetLastError` in each log output but the value is overwritten when boost::log calls another Windows API before the attribute value is queried. Anyone know a nice way around this?

```
class get_last_error_attribute_impl : public boost::log::attribute::impl {
public:
  boost::log::attribute_value get_value() {
    return boost::log::attributes::make_attribute_value(GetLastError());
  }
};

class get_last_error_attribute : public boost::log::attribute {
public:
  get_last_error_attribute() : 
    boost::log::attribute(new get_last_error_attribute_impl()) {
  }
};

void init_logging() {
  auto core = boost::log::core::get();
  core->add_global_attribute("GetLastError", get_last_error_attribute());

  auto sink = boost::make_shared<
    boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::debug_output_backend>>();
  sink->set_formatter(
    boost::log::expressions::stream
    << boost::log::trivial::severity
    << ": " << boost::log::expressions::smessage
    << " (" << boost::log::expressions::attr<DWORD>("GetLastError") << ")"
  );

  core->add_sink(sink);
}

void main() {
  init_logging();

  if (!DeleteFileA("c:\\foo.bar")) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "delete failed";
  }
}
```

Log output:

> warning: delete failed (0)

Comment: I'd make a logger that eagerly gets the value *or* wrap the log invocation in my own macro to do it. Also, I don't think you should be doing that. It just gives me the feeling it's being used as a way to ignore error handling.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using an assert to capture `GetLastError` instead

```
#define BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER 1
#include <boost/assert.hpp>

namespace boost {
  void assertion_failed([[maybe_unused]] char const* expr, [[maybe_unused]] char const* function, char const* file, long line) {
    auto err = GetLastError();
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << file << "(" << line << ") [" << err << "] assert failed";
    SetLastError(err);
  }
}

void init_logging() {
  auto sink = boost::make_shared<boost::log::sinks::synchronous_sink<boost::log::sinks::debug_output_backend>>();

  boost::log::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

void main() {
  init_logging();

  BOOL rc;
  BOOST_VERIFY(rc = DeleteFileA("c:\\foo.bar"));
  if (!rc) {
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "delete failed";
  }
}
```

Comment: So yeah, that's basically the "wrap it in your own macro" with extra steps (and omitting the "log with every message", which didn't seem like a natural thing to do anyways). Quite nice, TIL about `BOOST_ENABLE_ASSERT_HANDLER`

Comment: This solution is not quite correct, as `assertion_failed` is not expected to return. Similarly to `assert`, `BOOST_ASSERT` and `BOOST_VERIFY` are used in cases when the checked condition must be true, otherwise the behavior of the following code is undefined (by the contract with the caller). Typically, this means that the program should terminate if the assertion has failed. (In release mode the program doesn't terminate, but the behavior is undefined.) You should not use `BOOST_VERIFY` if you intend your program to continue execution after a failed assertion.

Comment: You can use the same approach as in this answer, but by defining your own macro instead of hijacking `BOOST_ASSERT`/`BOOST_VERIFY`.